# Is "it" grammatical or can it be omitted in "a problem that (it) will take them ages"?

Tags: grammar

1. The teacher decides to set them a problem that it will take them ages to actually do.
2. The teacher decides to set them a problem that will take them ages to actually do.

Considering the sentence "Junior is six months into cancer treatment that will take him three years to complete" [in a tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/scottkornberg/status/1156391611347197952), my sense is that the second sentence is also right. The impersonal subject or false subject "it" can be omitted in the first sentence. Am I right?

Comment: I've never heard of "setting [someone] a problem".  Is this homework?  What is your thinking for why each of the two is correct?

Comment: Thanks for making the edit!  You're partially correct in that "it" can be omitted in the first sentence.  In reality, it *should* be omitted from the first sentence; it doesn't work as it is now.  Replacing "that" with "and" (as mentioned by AdrianHHH) is another possibility, but I personally don't recommend it as much as simply removing "it", as the resulting sentence with "and" is choppier.

Comment: @myacorn Thank you very much.

Comment: @myacorn - From Oxford Dictionaries: _give someone (a task or test) to do.
"schools will begin to set mock tests"_ Perfectly normal in British English.

Comment: @Laurel Thank you very much for your editing.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Both are grammatically correct. I will simplify the sentences to explain what's going on:

- A problem that it will take them ages to do is unacceptable.
- A problem that will take them ages to do is unacceptable.

In both of these, *that...do* is a relative clause modifying "problem". But the understood role of "problem" in relation to "take ages them ages to do" is different.

We can simplify further by rephrasing without relative clauses:

- It will take them ages to do the problem. (This is an example of what's known as *it*-extraposition. A less natural phrasing without extraposition: "To do the problem will take them ages.")
- The problem will take them ages to do. (Or: "The problem will take ages for them to do.")

A similar pattern can be seen with words like "tough" and "easy":

- It is a tough problem to do. (Relative clause: "a problem that it is tough to do")
- The problem is tough to do. (Relative clause: "a problem that is tough to do")

Answer (score 0):

"... problem that it will take ..." does not read nicely. Changing to "... problem and it will take ..." is better. The "to actually do" can be omitted from both versions.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the comment by user myacorn  I think that the second version is not just acceptable, but better.

> (2) The teacher decides to set them a problem that will take them ages to actually do.

I think this would be improved further by removing "actually" which adds nothing here, and by replacing "do" with a mode descriptive word such as "finish" or "solve" resulting in:

> (3) The teacher decides to set them a problem that will take them ages to finish.

The use of "... problem and it will take ..." as suggested in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/305846/91457) is in my view not an improvement. The sense of connection between the teacher's decision and the time needed for the problem is lost (in the given sentence it is conveyed by "that"), and the sentence feels run-on to me.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first is not correct.  When the subject of the relative clause is the noun referred to by the relative pronoun, the explicit subject should be omitted.

The first leaves me puzzled, as I am looking for the reference of "it". Pragmatically "it" should mean "problem", but grammatically, it must mean something else ... But there is nothing else... So I am confused for a moment.

Eventually I'd understand the first to mean the same as the second. But the second is the only one in which the grammar matches the intended meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much.